# ggplot facet by column

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have this dataset here and was wondering how to create a ggplotted graph where
x = year, y = market_book_ratio, return_on_capital, return_on_equity, and return_on_assets. I know that's alota y variables, so I wanted to facet these variables. Ideally, my graph would have years on the x-axis and the y-values would be each variable for each facet with the company shown as different colors.... is this possible in ggplot?

[image]

I've tried:

```
 data %>% ggplot(aes(x = year, y = market_book_ratio, color = company)) +
         geom_line() +
         xlab("Year") +
         ylab("Market-To-Book Ratio") +
         facet_wrap(~.)
```

Comment: You need to convert the data from "wide" to "long" first: `library(tidyr); data %>% gather(key, value, -year, -company) %>% ggplot(aes(x=year, y=value, colour=company)) + facet_wrap(~ key) + (...all your other ggplot code)`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer given above is useful. Yet I want to rewrite a fuller version, maybe you will find it helpful as well. I treat the 4 columns as descriptions

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

data_long <- data %>%
    gather(Description, value, market_book_ratio:return_on_assets)

Company_analysis <- ggplot(data_long, aes(x = year, y= value, 
                           fill = Description), xlab="") +
    geom_bar(stat="identity", width=.5, position = "dodge") +
    labs(title="Company Figures") +
    theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 25, hjust = 1)) +
    facet_wrap(~company)
```

It will look fine, but if not, then you try to correct the `x=year` to `x=company`, and `facet_wrap(~company)` to `facet_wrap(~year)`

Hope it helps.